# rust-gdb pretty-print RwLock<HashMap>

Tags: rust

In debugger, pretty-print hash map is great.

```
(gdb) p h
$1 = HashMap(size=4) = {[1] = "Jan", [3] = "Mar", [2] = "Feb", [4] = "Apr"}
```

But it doesn't seem to work for RwLock

```
(gdb) p h
$1 = std::sync::rwlock::RwLockWriteGuard<std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<i32, &str, std::collections::hash::map::RandomState>> {lock: 0x7fffffffde98, poison: std::sync::poison::Guard {panicking: false}}
```

Is there a way how to pretty-print Hashmap inside RwLock?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
(gdb) p h.lock.data
$5 = core::cell::UnsafeCell<std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<i32, &str, std::collections::hash::map::RandomState>> {value: HashMap(size=4) = {[1] = "Jan", [4] = "Apr", [3] = "Mar", [2] = "Feb"}}
```